# android facebook publish opengraph crash

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using the code published on this tutorial (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/) by facebook the Publish an open graph story (under the topic: "Publish actions on user-owned objects")

```
OpenGraphObject meal = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("cooking-app:meal");
meal.setProperty("title", "Buffalo Tacos"); 
meal.setProperty("image", "http://example.com/cooking-app/images/buffalo-tacos.png");
meal.setProperty("url", "https://example.com/cooking-app/meal/Buffalo-Tacos.html");
meal.setProperty("description", "Leaner than beef and great flavor.");

OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
action.setProperty("meal", meal);

FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "cooking-app:cook", "meal")
    .build();
uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

The share dialog opens up (only after a few seconds of loading though) but for some reason before it finished loading the Facebook app crashes.

Anyone has experienced this before? Has anyone seen this happen and know the solution?

Sincerely,
Lior

Comment: After reading this in some other post, I've removed the "url" property and it works. Nice - but I still need the url... can anyone help me? please?

Comment: The code looks OK though the Builder with the parameters you specify is deprecated (3.5.2). Instead call action.setType("cooking-app:cook") and remove that parameter from the Builder. Most probably something outside this code is wrong: did you check if the Facebook app supports open graph posts? Is the action authorized for the user? etc

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
1. Try passing a different working URL - I am sure you have done this already but wanted to put it out there.
2. It is possible that the URL property for the meal object is looking for certain Meta tag information, Create your own custom objects on FB app interface and specify how to handle the URL properties manually.